# Time format error when seconds value is a multiple of 10

Tags: vba, excel

I think this is easy but since I'm fairly new in Excel VBA I can't figure it out.

I have a macro which converts the active cell format to `mm:ss`.
The input default pattern is *mm,ss* (comma because of keyboard issues of my country).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column <> 1 And Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, ",", ":")
    Target.Value = Target.Value / 60
    Target.NumberFormat = "mm:ss"

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

It works fine, but if the seconds value is a multiple of 10 it gets the first number as seconds unit.

Better show it in a example:

Input → Output

01,26 → 01:26            OK

**01,20 → 01:02**      WRONG

**01,50 → 01:05**      WRONG

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you step through the code (using F8) and hover over Target.Value, what happens to its value?

I wonder if the problem is to do with the 'keyboard issues' you mentioned... perhaps they alter/over-ride the value of Target.Value at your second step. Just a thought.

I'm new here so can't comment, so am using the Answer box instead.

BTW, not sure how 01,26 → 01:21  is OK?

Comment: thanks for your response. 
I noticed that this problem only happens with the comma (bad choice haha) maybe because it is the decimal separator in my country. 
I just changed it for a "m" which is easy for me to type in the same way, and it works perfect.